# Instant kernel crash when using `+=` on `SparseArray` with repeated entries

Tags: bugs, sparse-arrays, crash

**Bug introduced in 5.2 and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

Not sure if this is known behavior or not, but the following two lines produce an instant kernel crash (I'm using Mathematica 10.0.1 Windows 64-bit):

```
A = SparseArray[{}, {3, 3}];
A[[1, {1, 1}]] += 1
```

This is just a minor modification of the following lines:

```
A = SparseArray[{}, {3, 3}];
A[[1, {1, 2}]] += 1
```

which are designed to increment entries `{1,1}` and `{1,2}` of `A` by one. I would have expected the crash-inducing example to increment the `{1,1}` entry by two. Instead, I get screams of death.

Any clues as to what is going on here?

---

This slight variation produces a more apparent crash in 7.0.1:

```
A = SparseArray[{}, {3, 3}];
A[[1, {1, 2, 3, 1, 1}]] += 1
```

Comment: Crashes 9.0.1 as well. And 8.0.4. But not 7.0.1!

Comment: Reproduced with 10.0.2 on OS X.

Comment: obviously a crash is unacceptable, but those don't look like legal operations. What result are you expecting?

Comment: @george2079: The syntax `A[[k, list]] += 1` where `k` is a positive integer and `list` is a list increments all entries with indices $(k,m)\mid m\in\text{list}$ by one. This is a convenient one-line syntax for a multiple update within the $k$th row of a sparse matrix. Unfortunately, for some reason whenever `list` has a repeated element the kernel crashes. Of course, one possible workaround would be to simply construct a `Do` loop and iterate the sparse row update over the elements of `list`, but the aforementioned syntax makes things easier.

Comment: Yes, I should have tried it before commenting -- This does work with a plain array, the bug is only with `SparseArray`.  As a work around `A[[1, Union@{1, 1}]] += 1` works.

Comment: @Oleksandr This does shut down my 7.0.1 Kernel under Windows.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard can't reproduce that one...

Comment: @Oleksandr So `A` is actually modified correctly?  What about with `s = SparseArray[{}, {10, 10}]; s[[1, {1, 2, 3, 1, 1}]] += 1`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, the array is modified correctly. However, this is clearly a buggy area, as the code from the other question and the modified version you provide here both crash the kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed in 10.1 (windows)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
A = SparseArray[{}, {3, 3}];
A[[1, {1, 2, 3, 1, 1}]] += 1
```